# Get batch file return code in powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, exit-code

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script as a "Framework". Basically what it does is calls batch files that installs msi files locally.

There are few things I am trying to get done.

- PowerShell should get all exit codes whatever the batch files return.
- Need a timer and check if the batch file is stuck.If it's stuck kill it, return an error and continue
- Need a progress bar for each batch file installation.

I'm not sure if I can do all or any. Since every package(the batch files) comes from different groups, I can't use PowerShell to do everything and have to use the batch files other groups sent me.

I was able to get the packages install with a simple script but couldn't get to do any of the above things I was trying to do. I keep getting last exit code as 0. I assume it's because the batch file ran successfully.

```psh
$APP1 = "Microsoft_RDP_8.1_L_EN_01" 
Stop-Process -Name reg* -Force
Write-Host "=== $Time -- Starting $APP1 Installation"
TRY
    {
        $Install = "$pwd\cmd\$App1\Install.cmd"
        cmd /c $Install /b 1
        $App1ErrorCode = $LastExitCode
        Write-Host "Final Return Code Of $APP1 Is = $APP1ErrorCode"
    }
CATCH
    {
        Write-Host "-----------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host "Caught an exception:" -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Host "Exception Type: $($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)" -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Host "Exception Message: $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Host "-----------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Green
    }

$LastExitCode = $null   
$Value = $null
```

Comment: If the batch scripts don't return an exit code there's nothing you can do on your end to fix that.

Comment: Hi Ansgar,The batch file does return an exit code. But PowerShell doesn't see it. For example, the batch file might return a 1605 code but PowerShell returns 0.

Comment: I'm confused. Does PowerShell not *see* the exit code, or does it not *return* the exit code? Your code doesn' t instruct PowerShell to actually return anything, but a batch exit code of `1605` should be printed to the console as `Final Return Code Of Microsoft_RDP_8.1_L_EN_01 Is = 1605`.

Comment: PowerShell doesn't see the exit code. On the console it just shows that batch file ran but no matter what (batch file failed or not) PowerShell returns an exit code of 0. Although I tried searching and trying everything suggested, "cmd /c $install /b 1" part of the code was mentioned that should get the exit code from the batch and return it to PowerShell.

Comment: This is what the batch file returns
MSI Returncode: 1605
Done.
Final Return Code: 1605
--- End Un-Installation: Adobe ShockWave Player_12.0.2.122_L_EN_01 --- Fri 01/16/2015 10:59:52 ---
And this is what PowerShell Returns
0

Comment: Just because the batch script echoes something to the console doesn't mean it sets an actual return code. Please show a sample batch script.